# How to stop a Firebird 2.5 stored procedure from executing more than once at the same time

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

We have a Firebird 2.5 stored procedure that carries out multiple inserts & updates, and is called as a result of website actions, so can be called simultaneously.

We need to stop it running more than once at the same time, and I'm wondering whether there's a solution like there is with SQL server - something that can be called/set that effectively can 'lock' it on the way in, and 'unlocked' on the way out.

I appreciate that this is not the best solution - queuing being more satisfactory - but we need to get this sorted out quickly & don't have time to implement anything else at the moment. I think I recall seeing one somewhere, but have been unable to find any reference to it over the past few days.

Comment: you can abuse generators/sequences for that (see `gen_id` function), but in case your server or SP crashes without decrementing back the sequence - you might have the whole DB locked. // In general this seems to be very wrong approach, you better avoid locking! Instead formulate the data that can be processed in parrallel, for example instead of "x := 10" do "x := x +2", or do the "x := 10" but analyze maybe it is already that "x >= 10" and that rows has to be skipped, etc.

Comment: @Arioch'The You should write it as an answer.

Comment: there is also `select-for-update-with-lock` construct, but again, this anti-idiomatic for multi-version engine like Firebird and can create more subtle problems than solve. ENG: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-notes-withlock.html and RUS: https://www.sql.ru/forum/91047/select-for-update  // @user13964273 i am not sure what specific behavior Steve calls "locking". For example generators can make SP exit without doing anything, but it would be hard to make SP pause on the barrier, wait for it released and then continue. Same for WWW server "checking" lock and race-cond'ing SP call

Comment: Have you tried using the snapshot table stability isolation level? Also what do you want to happen when the stored procedure is 'locked'?